# How to replace image pixels in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to replace half of image1 pixels to first half of image2 pixel

```js
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    express = require('express');

var app = express(); 

 var image1 = "./img1.jpg";
 var image2 = "./img2.jpg";

  app.get("/",function(req,res){

  });


  app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
    console.log('server is runing');
});
```

Is there is a way to loop through and get the image1 pixels and replace it?

Comment: Do both images have the same size? And what do you mean "by replace half of image1 pixels to first half of image2"? Should the upper half of image1 be replaced by the upper half of image2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that both images have got the same size. You could use [PureImage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pureimage) to achieve this. By taking advantage of `drawImage` you can control where you want an image to be drawn onto another image. [`drawImage`](http://joshmarinacci.github.io/node-pureimage/class/src/context.js~Context.html#instance-method-drawImage) works just as the html5-canvas counterpart and fulfills your requirements best because you can cut an image and put this image-section onto any region of another image.

This example creates and returns a new image that contains the first upper half of `image2` and the lower half of `image1`:

```
let bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    express = require('express'),
    PImage = require('pureimage'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    app = express();

let image1 = "./img1.jpg";
let image2 = "./img2.jpg";

app.get("/", (req,res) => {
    PImage.decodeJPEGFromStream(fs.createReadStream(image1)).then((image1) => {
        // create newImage based on the size of image1
        let newImage = PImage.make(image1.width,image1.height);
        // get drawing context of newImage
        let c = newImage.getContext('2d');
        // 1. draw image1 on the whole canvas 1:1
        c.drawImage(image1,
            0, 0, image1.width, image1.height
        );
        PImage.decodeJPEGFromStream(fs.createReadStream(image2)).then((image2) => {
            // 2. draw only upper half of image2 onto newImage
            c.drawImage(image2,
                0, 0, image2.width, image2.height/2, // get only upper half of image2 -> sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight 
                0, 0, newImage.width, newImage.height/2 // draw upper half of image2 onto upper half of newImage -> destinationX, destinationY, destinationWidth, destinationHeight 
            );
            // 3. save newImage on filesystem and return it to client afterwards
            let pth = __dirname+"/newImage.jpg";
            PImage.encodeJPEGToStream(newImage,fs.createWriteStream(pth)).then(() => {
                console.log("done writing");
                res.sendFile(pth);
            });
        });

    });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, ()  => console.log('server is runing'));
```